# unable to run multiple thread groups parallel in Jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, automated-tests, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I am unable to run multiple thread groups in a single test plan parallel in Jmeter. 
I am using soap req in the HTTP sampler for the req using parameterise of the input values.
Please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Unchecked Run thread groups consecutively in Test Plan.

Hope this helps